# Use intersection of Sylow subgroup to prove no simple group of order 525

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Assume there exists a simple group with order $525$

$525 = 3*5*5*7$

we get $n_3 \in \{1, 5, 7, 25, 35, 150\}, n_5 \in \{1, 21\}, n_7 \in \{1, 3, 5, 15\}$

Assuming the group is simple $n_5 = 21, n_7 = 15, n_3 = 7 \, or \, 25$

now $|G| \nmid 8!$ so $n_3 = 25$

now using a lemma we get $21 \not\equiv 1 (mod\,25)$ thus $\exists P,R \in Syl_5(G)$ such that $P \cap R \neq \{e\}, P \neq R$ and $|P \cap R| \mid P , R$ so $|P,R : P \cap R| = 5 $ and $| P \cap R | = 5$

Consider $N_G(P\cap R) = N$ and must be that $5^2 \mid |N|$ so $|N| \in \{ 3\cdot 5^2, 7 \cdot 5^2, |G|\}$

if it's order is $3 \cdot 5^2$ or $7 \cdot 5^2$ by Cauchy there exists subgroups of order $3,7$ but we ruled those out thus $N = G$

contradiction

Comment: Observe that $\;n_3\;$ cannot be $\;5,35,150\;$ as these numbers aren't $\;1\pmod 3\;$, and $\;n_7\;$ can't be $\;3,5\;$ for a similar reason. I'd also say that $\;|G|\nmid 7!\implies n_3=25\;$ . What has $\;8!\;$ to do here isn't clear to me.

Comment: What's the question here?